# Scrapy unable to traverse to next page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to make scrapy be able to traverse to the next page to continue crawling, but it simply stops when the crawler and reached the end of the page. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class IT(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'IT'

    allowed_domains = ["www.jobstreet.com.sg"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?ojs=10&key=it',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="page_next"]',)), callback="self.parse", follow=True),
    )
```

Any idea how to make it work? Previously i used this snippet of code and the traversing works but it simply just always stops at page 7

```
next_page = response.xpath('//*[(@id = "page_next")]/@href')

if next_page:
    url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

EDIT:

```
    2017-09-09 15:48:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-09 15:48:35 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 16626,
 'downloader/request_count': 20,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 20,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 197475,
 'downloader/response_count': 20,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 20,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 9, 7, 48, 35, 66598),
 'item_scraped_count': 19,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 40,
 'log_count/INFO': 28,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'memusage/max': 45748224,
 'memusage/startup': 32595968,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 20,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 20,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 20,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 20,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 20,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 9, 7, 47, 1, 843551)}
2017-09-09 15:48:35 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
Exception twisted._threads._ithreads.AlreadyQuit: AlreadyQuit() in <bound method JobstreetPipeline.__del__ of <jobstreet.pipelines.JobstreetPipeline object at 0x103c152d0>> ignored
```

Current Code:

```
class IT(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'IT'

    allowed_domains = ["www.jobstreet.com.sg"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?ojs=10&key=it',
    ]

    rules = (
#       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="page_next"]',)), callback="self.parse", follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=("jobstreet.com.sg", ), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="page_next"]',)), callback='parse', follow=True),
    )

  def parse(self, response):  

        items = []
            ...
            ...
            ...
            item = JobsItems()
            ...
            ...
            ...
           item['jobdetailsurl'] = sel.xpath('.//a[@class="position-title-link"]/@href').extract()[0]

            request = scrapy.Request(item['jobdetailsurl'], callback=self.parse_jobdetails)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request
```

Comment: can you send link of website that you are scrapying.?

Comment: https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?ojs=10&key=it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues. `SgmlLinkExtractor` is deprecated. You should use `LinkExtractor`.

And `callback="self.parse"` should be the function name without self. And if you want to extract data from response then you should use another function

```
class IT(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'IT'

    allowed_domains = ["www.jobstreet.com.sg"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?ojs=10&key=it',
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=("jobstreet.com.sg", ), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="page_next"]',)), callback='parse_response', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_response(self, response):
        yield {"page": response.url}
```

**Edit-2**

I added `response.body` also to item yield and found below

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl="></script>\n\n    </head>\n\n\t<body>\n\n        <div id="main" class="main">\n            <div class="captchaDiv">\n\t\t\t\t<div id="headerDiv" class="headerDiv">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="insideHeaderDiv" class="insideHeaderDiv"></div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t<div class="separator"></div>\n\t\t\t\t<div id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="titleText" class="titleText">Security Check</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="instructionsText" class="instructionsText">Before we allow your access to this page, we need to confirm if you are a human (it\'s a spam prevention thing)</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=\'6LcX6A4UAAAAAKK1WiuMtXOj6Ib-lXZwVaWGvkq6\' data-callback=\'mprv_captcha_submitUserInput\'></div>\n\t\t\t\t\t<div id="footerText" class="footerText">SPAM Prevention</div>\n\t\t\t\t</div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n\t</body>\n</html>'
```

So the page shows a captcha after few request and hence the scraping stops there. You need to work around that by either slowing down request, or solving captcha somehow, or using a service like crawlera

**Edit-1**

Output from the crawl

```
2017-09-09 13:10:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?key=it&area=1&option=1&job-source=1%2C64&classified=1&job-posted=0&sort=2&order=0&pg=16&src=16&srcr=16> (referer: https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?key=it&area=1&option=1&job-source=1%2C64&classified=1&job-posted=0&sort=2&order=0&pg=15&src=16&srcr=16)
2017-09-09 13:10:06 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?key=it&area=1&option=1&job-source=1%2C64&classified=1&job-posted=0&sort=2&order=0&pg=16&src=16&srcr=16>
{'page': 'https://www.jobstreet.com.sg/en/job-search/job-vacancy.php?key=it&area=1&option=1&job-source=1%2C64&classified=1&job-posted=0&sort=2&order=0&pg=16&src=16&srcr=16'}
2017-09-09 13:10:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-09-09 13:10:06 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 15664,
 'downloader/request_count': 16,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 16,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 306524,
 'downloader/response_count': 16,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 16,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 9, 7, 40, 6, 294685),
 'item_scraped_count': 15,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 31,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 49135616,
 'memusage/startup': 49135616,
 'request_depth_max': 15,
 'response_received_count': 16,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 16,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 16,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 16,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 16,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 9, 7, 39, 56, 380899)}
2017-09-09 13:10:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: I changed to that but it doesn't traverse at all.

Comment: @dythe, if you check the output I ran it and it scraped 15 items

Comment: i edited my original post, it just scrap the first 20 items in page 1 and stops

Comment: @dythe, please check my edit-2, the site has scraping protecting using Google captcha

Comment: I already have a download delay of 6 seconds and 1 concurrent request with random user agent. Guess that doesn't help the detection by the captcha?

Comment: Nope, it would be request based on IP i believe

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for you pagination.

```
next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="page_next"]/@href').extract_first()

if next_page:
    yield scrapy.Request(next_page, self.parse)
```